# How to decrease the lineSpacing?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have an Attributed string and I want to decrease the standard line height of it. To do so, I need to set a negative `lineSpacing` to my `NSMutableParagraphStyle`. But it's illegal according to Apple's docs.

Fun fact is that the negative `lineSpacing` actually works, but causes an extra bottom spacing in the `UILabel` which depends on the number of lines.

[image]

Is it possible to decrease the line height without having side effects?

Comment: “I need to set a negative lineSpacing to my NSMutableParagraphStyle” Why do you need to do that? Just set it to a smaller positive number.

Comment: Matt, because I have a design using line spacing which is smaller than a standard one.

When I set `paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0` it gives a standard line spacing.

`paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.1` gives a 0.1 bigger line spacing as compered to the standard one.

Answer (score 3):

Use NSParagraphStyle.lineHightMultiple
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle/1528614-lineheightmultiple

You can set the lineHeightMultiple to a value greater than 0 but less than 1 and it'll reduce line spacing.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.83 //Try different values here to see what looks best

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your string")
attrString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
```

You can also do this from storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work accurate. Reducing lineHeightMultiple clips top and bottom label paddings but I'd like to avoid it. https://imgur.com/xeI0bJh